# Find the sum of the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, partial-fractions

Find the sum of the infinite series:
$$ \begin{align*}\frac{1}{2.3.4}+\frac{1}{4.5.6} +\frac{1}{6.7.8}+\frac{1}{8.9.10} + \ldots 
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2))} \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)} \\
&=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n}-\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}+\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2(2n+2)} \\
&= \frac14+\frac14+\frac16+\ldots 1-\frac12-\frac14-\frac16-\ldots -1+\frac12-\frac13+\frac14 \ldots \\
&=1+\frac14-\frac12-\ln2 \\
&=\frac{1}{4}[3-4\ln2]
\end{align*} $$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1/2}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1/2}{n+2}$$

Comment: Add to BAI, I think use $\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1/2}{n+1}+\frac{1/2}{n+1}$ .... you will get a telescopic sum, I guess.

Comment: I don't understand why it is still written "on hold"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2))}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4}[3-4\ln2]
\end{equation}

Comment: How have you reached at the last equality?

Comment: Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev, Integrals and Series Volume 1 Elementary Functions, 1986, pg 666.

Comment: It's done thanks alot.

Comment: I checked it's ans is $\frac34-ln2$